# Why Gitlab fails importing repository from local network with status code 128?

Tags: git, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have recently installed GitLab with Docker in a server within a local network. I am trying to migrate a repository I mantained locally in my PC. **I exposed it through a local HTTP server within my local network as a workaround, just to be able to import it to GitLab**, because almost all options available in GitLab admin Panel are like "Import from GitHub", and none of those options will help in my case (I mean: couldn't I just upload my repository's `.git` folder to import it? -retorically speaking) By the way, the one I chose was "Repo by URL":

[image]

There's a security setting that I had to disable, because GitLab doesn't allow importing from URLs that point towards a server in your local network. So I turned on the option called "Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services" within the Outbound Services section.

Then, I tried making a new project from GitLab, using the tab called "import project" and filling the form within it. Then, it keeps running for a long while with the message "Importing..." looks like it keeps retrying over and over, until this message is shown:

> Every import attempt has failed: Error importing repository http://111.222.33.44/path/to/my/repository/root/folder/.git into myuser/my_project - 13:CreateRepositoryFromURL: clone cmd wait: exit status 128. Please try again.

I have been reading the Gitlab Manual posted online, different articles about GitLab, googled about this error and found tens of tickets with similar (but very different!) issues... But I still don't understand: why can't I just upload my repository right away?

The URL given is not the problem *per se*: if I type it into a web browser, I can see clearly the entire filesystem of my project within the web browser, and, if I add `/.git` to it, I can even see the hidden `.git` folder's content in my browser... but, for some reason, this isn't enough for GitLab...

I am very confused about this. One of the links I found is [Export a repository from a Gitlab server to another Gitlab server](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/163763c) (Please notice I am mot importing from other Gitlab, but a simple git repository created in a PC with a simple `git init`. Finding reading material about something remotely similar to my case isn't a piece of cake: I have been searching about this the whole day, without success...). Within that link, there is a part that says:

> You will get warnings that you cloned an empty repository. This is normal. Change into the working directory of your checked out repository and do a git pull

...so I found the folder where my GitLab installation created the "empty repository", and tried executing the `git pull` command from there, giving it the route to my other local server machine. Something similar to this:

```
git pull http://111.222.33.44/path/to/my/repository/root/folder/my_project.bundle
```

...just after succeeding making a `.bundle` file on the other side, following the instructions I found in the above link. But, for some reason, my GitLab server's CLI doesn't find the command `git`! (Perhaps is is wrapped on some kind of `virtualenv`? Or rather it wasn't included in `PATH` in the first place? Who knows...). In any case, pull to **where**? There's no working directory to pull from!

Is there something else I could do about this? My knowledge about Git is limited: I have almost always used it to mantain repositories on my own, all alone, without the need to `push` them anywhere, neither `pull` them from anywhere (with the rare exception of one GitHub project of mine).

I might add that [the official Gitlab's manual about howto import projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/) includes instructions to migrate from everywhere, except the original, unwrapped, unsugared, normal `git` command-line software!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: I think you might be taking the wrong approach here.  I recently migrated a git repo from a local filesystem to Bitbucket.  BB doesn't have a built-in option to import a repo from a file, either.  I ended up needing to switch the remote URL to a "fresh" repo in BB and then do a merge.  Worked like a charm :)

Comment: In my case, almost every step-by-step guide I find is out of context for some reason (I barely can explain it, but it's like everyone of them, when I look carefully at them, I just can yell: that's not my case!). In addition, `git` is not present on the system's `PATH` envvar... so i do a `find -name git` from the unit's root folder and I find several of them spread around... which of them can I rely on? Everything is just too confusing...

Comment: I managed to find the folder where `GitLab` created the "empty repo" (probably triggered by GitLab's importing form). It's like it puts a folder like `myproject.git` for every single project I try to import. Those folder's contents are suspiciosly similar to any `.git` folder present in any repository made using `git` in a CLI... but there's no working tree at all!

Comment: @Brian I don't think my question is a duplicate of the one you posted for at least two reasons: 1- I am using GitLab, the OP of the other question isn't. 2- GitLab doesn't add `git` into the `PATH` envvar. I have no other option to do it according to the GitLab's structure.

Comment: @Brian Indeed, my problem is more similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518323/gitlab-repository-does-not-exists-issue) than to the one you referenced as duplicate.

Comment: I was thinking that the second answer from the link would apply -- I used a similar procedure for the Bitbucket import I mentioned yesterday.  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, the true problem was a misunderstanding with how GitLab's web menu works, actually.

When you click "New Project" in GitLab's web interface, there are 3 tabs to pick from:

- Blank Project
- Create from template
- Import Project

I wasn't thinking that "Blank project" would be the way to go... I mean... "I am trying to import my project into GitLab" was my idea, so I waS TRYING FROM "Import Project" tab (and that's why I ended up posting this question)... but, trying from "Blank Project" solved my issue.

I was just giving up my commit history and trying to make a new repository from scratch, from my current's project files' state. But, unexpectedly, after creating the "blank project", GitLab gave me instructions to import my repository into this "blank project". I quote:

```
CMD Instructions - Existing Git repository

cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin http://gitlab.somedomain.net/myuser/someblank-domain.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

**And thus, a "blank project" became an "imported project".** Problem solved!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error `Error importing repository http://111.222.33.44/path/to/my/repository/root/folder/.git into myuser/my_project - 13:CreateRepositoryFromURL: clone cmd wait: exit status 128. Please try again.`.

In my case I had to provide a username and password, since the repository I imported from was secured with that (gitblit). I tried also many ways, but in the end it seems to be a GitLab glitch. For me using the provided fields `Username (optional)` and `Password (optional)` **didn't work!** I had to provide the credentials directly inside the `Git repository URL` field ([as the old screenshot in the docs also suggest](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html)):

[image: gitlab import page]

With that the import worked like a charm - and at great speed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the root cause of this issue was that my password (a temporary HTTP password created by Gerrit) had special characters in it. I had to keep generating passwords until I was given one without special characters.